# How to read byte by byte from appengine datastore Entity Object

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

In a nutshell, since GAE cannot write to a filesystem, I have decided to persist my data into the datastore (using JDO). Now, I will like to retrieve the data byte by byte and pass it to the client  as an input stream. There's code from the gwtupload library(http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) (see below) which breaks on GAE because it writes to the system filesystem. I'll like to be able to provide a GAE ported solution.

```
public static void copyFromInputStreamToOutputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
    while (true) {
      synchronized (buffer) {
        int amountRead = in.read(buffer);
        if (amountRead == -1) {
          break;
        }
        out.write(buffer, 0, amountRead);
      }
    }
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  }
```

One work around I have tried (didn't work) is to retrieve the data from the datastore as a resource like this:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = null;
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        Query q = pm.newQuery(ImageFile.class);
        lf  = q.execute();
        resourceAsStream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream((String) pm.getObjectById(lf));
    } finally {
      pm.close();
    }
    if (lf != null) {
      response.setContentType(receivedContentTypes.get(fieldName));
      copyFromInputStreamToOutputStream(resourceAsStream, response.getOutputStream());

    }
```

I welcome your suggestions.

Regards

Comment: Are you trying to serialize POJOs between client/server?

Comment: No! I'm basically trying to upload a file to GAE, using GWT for the client. While doing the upload, I want to monitor it byte by byte, like a progress bar or % reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store data in a byte array, and use a `ByteArrayInputStream` or `ByteArrayOutputStream` to pass it to libraries that expect streams.

If by 'client' you mean 'HTTP client' or browser, though, there's no reason to do this - just deal with regular byte arrays on your end and send them to/from the user as you would any other data. The only reason to mess around with streams like this is if you have some library that expects them.